# H2 Cluster Setup

Tags: java, transactions, cluster-computing, h2

Since H2 supports clustering and the process is pretty much like:

- start servers
- use `java org.h2.tools.CreateCluster` in order to replicate database among the desired cluster

And knowing that `CreateCluster` expects *one* target, *one* source and a *list* of cluster end-points I have the following questions:

1. Am I right when I say that **in order to start a cluster of 3 servers (A, B and C) I need to know exactly the number of servers on the cluster** because each server needs to have the list of DB servers for the `SET CLUSTER` statement on `org.h2.tools.CreateCluster.process(String, String, String, String, String)` method invocation.

   - start server A;
   - start server B;
   - start server C;
   - execute on B machine `CreateCluster` with A as source, B as target and A,B,C as cluster list;
   - execute on C machine `CreateCluster` with B as source, C as target and A,B,C as cluster list;
2. Suppose I'm in starting process of the service and **started A and B**, the application started to **execute a few SQL over the cluster**. C is not found, **will C be handled as down**?
3. Continuing the start process initiated on second question, I **started C** and I'm ready to execute `CreateCluster` having B as source and A,B,C as cluster nodes list, in this very moment two things happen:

   - B will be locked in exclusive mode (`SET EXCLUSIVE 2`) due to `CreateCluster`
   - the SQL `SET CLUSTER 'A,B,C'` will be executed on B and C

The **SQLs executed while B is locked, are they executed in A?** If so are they already **committed?** And when **B is released will the client be still waiting? Afterwards will C be notified of this command?**

Comment: I have similar question and would be very interested to know if you found an answer to yours.